# How to reuse content accessing by url and conditional statement in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app I have a slidebox style interface. In one of the slides, I want to show a certain thing conditionally (ie `if Meteor.user().profile.asdf`). I want to show the exact same page via navigation from a link on the main page (so if you're at the URL `/item/123`). How can I do this without duplicating all of my code? More specifically, in my router I have:

```
.state('item', {
  url: '/item/:itemId',
  templateUrl: 'client/templates/itemView.html',
  controller: 'itemViewCtrl as item',
  resolve : {
    liftId : ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
      // console.log($stateParams.liftId);
      return $stateParams.liftId;
    }]
  }
})
```

On the page accessed via the URL I access the data through item.helper.whatever. Is there a shortcut to include this page in the main page as an `<ng-include src="'client/templates/itemView.html'"></ng-include>` or something?

Answer (score 0):

Angular should do that automatically if the `templateUrl` is the same for both components.  Angular uses a `$templateCache`.  [Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)

When angular goes to fetch you URL it will check the `$templateCache` first and will realize the template is from the same place and not fetch the static content again.  Instead it will use the one stored in `$templateCache`

---

You can validate this by looking at your network traffic in developer tools.  Only one request for that url should be sent.

If it is not, or you want to make sure you are using the same exact template another approach is to manually add a template to the cache using.

`$templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');`

Then instead of using `templateUrl` for your `State` you would use `template`

Comment: So I think it's not working because the first way to access the age goes through `index/itemView/123`, and the other is just via `index/`. When it goes though `index/itemView/123`, it snags the ID from the `$stateParams` and uses that to dynamically load data. There's no `$stateParams` in the other way, so it doesn't know what data to load into the template.